# Loop on content script breaks after first pass - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that expands all collapsed text on a a web page.
Heres a snippet of the code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "filterq2",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_16.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Preguntas"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.quora.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

contentScript.js

```
function eventFire(el, etype) {
    if (el.fireEvent) {
        el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
        var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
        evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
        el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}

var losExpandibles = document.getElementsByClassName("ui_qtext_more_link");
for (var i = 0; i < losExpandibles.length; i++) {
    eventFire(losExpandibles[i], 'click');
}
```

I try to simulate a left click of the mouse on every element with class name: "ui_qtext_more_link" but the for loop breaks after first pass.
But if I run it in the console it works on every element just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: When you get different results from a content script and from the console the difference usually is the state of the DOM. The page might have not finished loading when your content script executes. Try adding a few seconds of delay before running your logic to check it that is the problem.

Comment: It makes sense but I tried adding a "if (document.readyState != 'loading')" else Window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", runWhenPageIsFullyParsed) hoping it would then get all the elements but I get the same result

Comment: That won't help if the content is loaded dynamically after the rest of the page has loaded like it is the case on Quora. You can see the loading animation popping up for a second after render for the answers. You need to execute after that completes. You have a couple of options to make that happen:
a, best, but most difficult: mutation observer
b, quick and dirty: add a simple delay.
c, quick and perhaps less dirty: rerun your logic periodically. 
Let me know if you want me to expand on those.

Comment: I appreciate it, please expand option a. Tried option b didn't work

Comment: Mutation observers let you observe changes to the DOM, in your case you should find the element that gets filled with the contents and after this happens execute your logic. Quora's DOM is pretty messy and the content loads quickly but if you refresh the page and quickly pause js execution with F8 you can observe the DOM's state. I have checked it myself, the loading placeholder animation has the classes: 'spinner_display_area paged_list_hidden_footer'. You could also check if (document.querySelector('.spinner_display_area.paged_list_hidden_footer') is null, then the content has loaded.

Comment: That's very helpful I'll work with that. Thank you!